# Iterate object with custom index keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have the following object, and I want to iterate and check the value of each object i.e. `requestArr.st.value` and if there is a value, then return the expr value.

```js
var x = 12345
var y
const requestArr = {
  oj: {
    "value": x,
    "expr": "testX"
  },
  st: {
    "value": y,
    "expr": "testY"
  },
};

console.log(requestArr.oj.value)
console.log(requestArr.st.value)

for (const [index, key] of Object.keys(requestArr).entries()) {
 console.log(key)
}
```

Currently I can get the object index  `console.log(key)` how do I navigate to test if there is a value and then return the expr?

**update**
I am still getting the expression for undefined value, I only want to return the expr for objects that contain a value in the value node.

```
for (const [index, key] of Object.keys(requestArr).entries()) {
  if (requestArr[key].value !== '' || requestArr[key].value !== undefined) {
    console.log(requestArr[key].value)
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a question about how to complete this task?

Comment: if you have key then you can check if (requestArr[key].value === undefined)

Comment: I think your after -> `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(requestArr))`

Comment: You don't need the `index` of the array, perhaps you meant to use `Object.entries` instead `for (const [key, obj] of Object.entries(requestArr)) { if (obj.value} console.log(obj.expr);}`

Comment: your new if short circuits after first condition. since `requestArr[key].value !== ''` becomes true when it is undefined therefore goes inside. use an and statement instead of or

Comment: Are you seeing the Undefined printed by the console.log above the for loop?

Comment: I forgot to mention my js rendering engine is ES5 <-------------------

Comment: @DavidGarcia with es5 you can go with Object.keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the value of any key inside the Array by using the square brackets as such:

```
requestArr[key]
```

Using the key you have in the for loop you can test if the value is undefined by using:

```
if(requestArr[key].value != undefined) {
```

and then outputting the value if its not undefined as below:

```
if(requestArr[key].value != undefined) {
  console.log(requestArr[key].value)
 }
```

Below I have added this to your code:

```js
var x = 12345
var y
const requestArr = {
  oj: {
    "value": x,
    "expr": "testX"
  },
  st: {
    "value": y,
    "expr": "testY"
  },
};

for (const [index, key] of Object.keys(requestArr).entries()) {
 console.log("Key: " + key)
 if(requestArr[key].value != undefined) {
  console.log("Value not Undefined: " + requestArr[key].value)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the `Object.values` using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
Object.values(requestArr).filter(entry => entry['value']);
```

You can then add `Array.forEach` method anNd do whatever you want to do with the `entry`:

```js
Object.values(requestArr)
  .filter(entry => entry['value'])
  .forEach(entry => console.log(entry['expr']);
```

### ES5

If you use ES5, as you updated your question, you need to loop over the object keys and map them to the object values like:

```js
Object.keys(requestArr)
  .map(function (key) {
    return requestArr[key];
  })
  .filter(function (entry) {
    return entry['value'];
  })
  .forEach(function (entry) {
    console.log(entry['expr']);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate though object keys using for...in loop and inside loop check if requestArr[key].value exist then perform operation or store it in some array like this

```
for(const key in requestArr){
    if(requestArr[key].value){
        console.log(requestArr[key].expr);
        // perform your stuff
    }
}
```

Useinng Array.entries() method, you can use Array.forEach or Array.map as well,

```
const displayValue = (key) => {
  if(requestArr[key].value){
        console.log(requestArr[key].expr);
        // perform your stuff and return value for Array.map and Array.filter
    }
}
// Array.entries
Object.keys(requestArr).entries(displayValue);
// Array.forEach 
Object.keys(requestArr).forEach(displayValue);
// Array.map 
Object.keys(requestArr).map(displayValue);
// Array.filter     
Object.keys(requestArr).filter(displayValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 12345
var y
const requestArr = {
  oj: {
    "value": x,
    "expr": "testX"
  },
  st: {
    "value": y,
    "expr": "testY"
  },
};


for (key in requestArr) {
  if (requestArr[key].value) {
    console.log(requestArr[key].expr)
  }
}
```

Comment: be sure to declare your variables `for (const key ...`

Comment: You're right! I'm actually a Python developer )

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `Object.entries` to access both **key** and **value**:

```js
var x = 12345;
var y;
const requestArr = {
  oj: {
    "value": x,
    "expr": "testX"
  },
  st: {
    "value": y,
    "expr": "testY"
  },
};

const validExpressions = Object.entries(requestArr)
  .map(([key, entry]) => !!entry.value && entry.expr)
  .filter((value) => !!value);

console.log(validExpressions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to invoke for `.entries()` ? you do not even use the `index`.

This is much simpler and direct to the point in my opinion. And should solve your problem:

Instead of

```
for (const [index, key] of Object.keys(requestArr).entries())
```

replace it with

```
for (const key of Object.keys(requestArr))
```

**You are still getting the undefined value because** you are using an `||` operator in your `if` statement. This should be using the `&&`,

```
if (requestArr[key].value !== '' && requestArr[key].value !== undefined)
```

You can further simplify this condition with
`if (requestArr[key].value)`

TLDR:

Replace your `for` loop with this:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(requestArr)) {
  if (requestArr[key].value) console.log(requestArr[key].value)
}
```